# How to keep a track of file that populated destination in SSIS ForEach File enumerator?

Tags: foreach, ssis, ssis-2012, foreach-loop-container

I have a source folder from where I have to extract only text files and load into a Database. I could do that using Foreach file enumerator.
I also want to maintain a column at Destination(OLEDB) which would keep a track of the file that populated the corresponding record.[This is precisely what I want at my destination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB3my.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach numerator you could assign the filenames to a variable. Add that to a derived column, and populate in your destination. Here is an example how you could do it:

[image]

Add your variable to derived column

[image]

Comment: Thankyou!! Worked!

Comment: Vote the answer instead, so others can benefit from it.